# Help me Describe Why this Happens to my Client

Tags: images, png, jpeg

I am having issues with my colleague opening my designs and telling me they are appearing too big or too small. This banner I actually created in Canva because I will have to create it for every brand in the company once it gets approved. (in the picture I've removed our company logo)

This is a recurring problem where he asks me why one is so large or why some are small. I have explained that it has to do with what it contained in the image-- this image is fairly plain and simple so when he clicks on it, it appears large, but it IS the correct size for our site.

Am I explaining this correctly? Or am I wrong?

[image: Example banner]

Answer (score 4):

Whether it is "big" or "small" depends entirely on the application used to view it & how it interprets the DPI value assigned [or not assigned] to that image.

The DPI value, commonly 72, 96 or up to 300 for print are actually all entirely arbitrary & have no real value until you do actually need to print your image.

Your image, as posted, is 1920 x 720 pixels. That is its "true size" no matter what DPI may have been assigned to it [any DPI data, along with most other exif data, is stripped by the upload to imgur when you publish on stack exchange]

On a "Full HD" screen with no other consideration, that image would fill approximately ⅔ of the screen vertically, full-width horizontally.

Your brief will presumably have dictated a set of **dimensions in pixels** you need to supply your artwork at. Those are the figures you need to supply at. Don't let anyone specify image sizes to you in inches [or centimetres], only in pixels, then there's no argument.

Comment: thank you- this helps. I have never had this question asked of me so many times-- and it's becoming an issue- but the file size is always correct-- I cannot help it if "looks too big" on the preview-- it's simply NOT.

Comment: @CarolynMaszczak Also note many laptops have actually zoom enabled